# SQL: Sort list for children shoe sizes

Tags: mysql, sql

As of right now I have a list that puts out shoe sizes.
This is what the list looks like for example.

1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 12, 13.5

And I need it to look like this 
10, 10.5, 11, 12, 13.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5

Thank you I know you can do this with an ORDER BY but I have failed. Thank you
Here is what example of what I tried.

```
ORDER BY priority=0, priority asc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can project a computation of the ordering, you can then use this in the ORDER BY, e.g. in your example it seems that by adjusting sizes `10+` to below the `<10` sizes, and then still ordering ascending:

```
SELECT * FROM Shoes 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN Size >= 10 
       THEN Size - 20 
       ELSE Size 
  END ASC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44b69/1)

Comment: 10 13.5 12 11 10.5 1 1.5 2

I use txt50_variation_name and the variation looks like this:

1.5 MEDIUM (M) and so on for all sizes

Comment: It looks like you may be ordering by something else as well - the Sizes should be in order. Can you change the SqlFiddle please to include the relevant data and repeat the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should add another column to your sizes table 'size_type'.  The new column should have two possible values: adult and child.

You would do your first sort on the 'size_type' column and your second sort on the size column.